# It is risky to modify the App part appearance setting (width & Height) using fixed pixel numbers

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, page-layout

I have added many App parts to my team site web page, such as calendar, announcements, document management, etc.

Then I modify the App part width and height by defining 300 pixel for its height instead of using “Adjust height to it zone”. I tested the above inside my development machine which have a resolution of 1900 x 1050, and it will show a tool bar inside the App part and it worked fine.

But in general is it risky to define fixed pixel number to define the app part width and height?, since end users will be accessing the team site using different resolution settings , any advice eon this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right. The risk is that someone viewing it on a smaller resolution screen or heaven forbid their phone will not see the page laid out the way you had it laid out. Generally, fixed-width items tend to sit side by side or above and below each other but it's possible that the underlying CSS *could* make them overlap if it's built for web parts that don't have fixed sizes.

Incidentally, SP Designer 2013 has a previewer you can use for multiple browsers with different shapes and sizes. I think it goes down to 800x600, which is still a bit bigger than some phone screens, but it should give you an idea of how an app part might look on a page.

Comment: i know i can test my application on different screen resolution, but i am asking as pevention question. as fixed width can cause problems. and i was wondering why the App part Apperance setting inside sharepoint do not have the option to provide relative values such as 30% of the screen width ?